# Pandoc lua filter to move image caption at the end of the document

Tags: templates, lua, latex, pandoc

I'm totally new to Lua pandoc filter so this problem is over my level.

Starting from a markdown document, I want to collect all figures in the manuscript, remove the latex call to display them, capture their captions and display them in a block at the end called Figures.

For example, figures are rendered in the intermediate .tex as:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figure1} \caption{Figure 1. Caption.}\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
```

I want to remove the afore mentioned block, take the caption and move it in the (existing) Figure section with this structure:

```
\section*{Figures}
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \caption{Figure 1. Caption.}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \caption{Figure 2. Caption.}
  \end{figure}
```

I want to stress that the figures should not be shown anymore in the final document. This structure is required by the journal I'm sending the .tex to, which require the pictures to be loaded separately and just keep a reference to them in the manuscript.

I tried some Lua coding with no luck. But then I discovered that lua was not seeing at all my images.

I put this into the .md file:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figure1} \caption{Figure 1. Caption.}\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
```

and then trying to check how it was seen by Lua with:

```
function Para (el) print(pandoc.utils.stringify(el)) end
```

But no reference to the image was printed (the other elements were printed, as a test). I tried substituting Para for Str, Inline, Image, Pandoc but nothing.

So I am not even able to catch the figure in the AST...

Comment: I just noticed that my lua filter sees only what's in the intermediate .md, not in the .tex before being turned into pdf... another problem here...

Comment: Can you say how do you create the intermediary tex files? What does the input look like for these figures?

Comment: I am using rmarkdown to generate the .tex and the pdf. But I'm not sure I answered your question...

Comment: I think I I wasn't sure if you're using raw LaTeX snippets, R Markdown commands, or the `![figure caption](image/path.png)` syntax. I interpreted the above to mean that you are using plain LaTeX, but wasn't sure.

Comment: yes sorry, I was trying to simplify the problem. the pictures are either loaded or generated by R in the .Rmd file. The latex code I wrote above is how the figures are represented in the .tex file before being turned into a pdf

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks! R Markdown has to do some sophisticated things, as pandoc's figure handling is still very basic. It's *probably* all raw LaTeX when it reaches pandoc, but some of the figures may be passed as a single `Image` element wrapped in a `Para`.

Comment: I tried also with custom images and the are recognized as RawBlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with putting raw LaTeX into your R Markdown input is that it will not be processed by pandoc, but is passed through verbatim. That can be very useful, but in this case it limits the usefulness of Lua filters. However, the `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` code becomes a "raw block" in pandoc, and can still be accessed from Lua filters via `RawBlock`. You might be able to collect the captions with code similar to this:

```lua
local captions = pandoc.List()

function RawBlock (raw)
  local caption = raw.text:match('\\caption%{(.*)%}')
  if caption then
    captions:insert(caption)
  end
end

function Pandoc (doc)
  -- append collected captions at the end
  doc.blocks:insert(captions:map(function(x) return pandoc.Para(x) end))
  return doc
end
```

Or to put all figures into a metadata field:

```
function Pandoc (doc)
  doc.meta.figures = captions:map(function (c)
      return pandoc.RawBlock('latex', c)
  end)
  return doc
end
```

Comment: thanks! I was getting there but your code is way cleaner! I'm focusing on passing through Meta to create a variable that can be used in the template. but doing simply `meta.figures = caption` (at the moment I'm trying with one figure only) it outputs in the .tex: `\textbackslash caption\{Figure 1. Example caption\}`, which is not read by pdflatex. How can I pass the raw latex through meta to the template?

Comment: You can mark the caption as raw TeX like so: `meta.figures = pandoc.RawBlock('latex', caption)`. I believe that should do it.

Comment: I get the error: "Could not get Pandoc value: Could not get Meta value: Could not read value of key-value pair: Could not get MetaValue: Unknown meta tag: RawBlock". Let me clean the code and post it into the question

Comment: Ah, right, that'd only work with new pandoc versions. Try to wrap the value in `{...}`, as in `meta.figures = {pandoc.RawBlock(...)}`

Comment: I made a gist: https://gist.github.com/bakaburg1/9df96ad28f0a83c6594e582c56ace304
unfortunately I am still not able to make RawBlock works.

Comment: Still not able to solve the problem with RawBlock, but as a workaround I extracted the caption text itself removing the latex with gsub. BTW: does regex lookaround not work in LUA?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include code for the metadata-based solution. Please note that the first line of my code is missing from the linked gist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242500/discussion-between-bakaburg-and-tarleb).

Comment: btw, images generated by R are indeed seen as Image by lua, not RawBlocks as for imported images.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of actually moving the figures, you can just tell latex to show the captions at the end:

```
\usepackage{figcaps}
```

Comment: thanks, the problem is that I don't want the actual figures to be printed anymore, just their captions added after \section*{Figures} in order to respect the templating rules of the journal I'm sending the .tex to. They want the figures as external files and just a reference to them in the main .tex (I should mention this in the question)

Comment: @Bakaburg Ah, I think I understand. On can probably redefine `\includegraphics` temporarily, let me test this...

Comment: @Bakaburg There is actually a dedicated package for this. Please check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks! but still, the problem is that I'm sending them the .tex, not the pdf. So I need to respect their templating structure! I could do this manually but I would like to have a general solution (also to learn)