# Rmarkdown with pandoc templates, apply lua filter on intermediate .tex

Tags: lua, r-markdown, pandoc, templating

I'm trying to use lua filters to capture images in my manuscript and list their caption in a special \section at the end of it.
I am working on a rmarkdown document that itself uses a .tex template.

I wasn't able to get anywhere, so I run a very simple filter:

```
function Header (head) print(pandoc.utils.stringify(head)) end
```

and noticed that just the headers in the markdown were recognized, not the ones in the ones in the template.

The only way I found to have lua filters recognize the elements in the template was to rerun the produced .tex file with pandoc:

```
pandoc -f latex -t latex -o test2.tex --lua-filter=my_filters.lua test.tex
```

but that removed all latex formatting and structure content outside the body, e.g., \documentclass, \usepackage and other custom commands. So it's a no go.

So the question is, is there a way to force lua filter to be applied after the integration of a latex template when knitting a rmarkdown document?

Comment: See [the docs](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html), specifically [this section](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-header): Your filter will only be applied to just headers because it is in a function that is only called for headers. If you want the entire document, you should take a look at [this section](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-pandoc).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I wasn't clear enough. I used Header just as an example, the problem is that only the initial markdown is parsed by the filter, not the latex document generated by integrating the markdown with the latex template. The only workaround I found was to just generate the .tex via rmarkdown and reuse pandoc on it to generate the final pdf

Comment: I'm editing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way, but it most likely won't do what you need.

When pandoc reads a document, it parses it and converts it into it's internal data structure. That internal structure can then be modified with a filter. LaTeX is a very expressive and complex document format, and any conversion from LaTeX into pandoc's internal format will result in a loss of (layout) information. That's good enough in most cases, but would be a problem in your case.

There are two possible ways to do this: one is to post-process the output, which is probably tedious and error-prone. The other is to find a way to generate the desired output, e.g. via a pandoc filter, without adding it to the template first.

I believe your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71286208/) is the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying two approaches now (more related to the linked other question): 1. add figure captions into Meta which is then read from the template (works, but adds an annoying \textbackslash which invalid the appended latex code; should be easy to solve). 2. create the section in the markdown and add figures there. Of course I prefer the first since it's cleaner.

Comment: I didn't mention that I need to do the same with tables, but I'm not sure I'll be able to store them into Meta to send them to the template. one problem at time