# pandoc md -> latex write lua-filter to change latex-macro used for caption

Tags: filter, lua, pandoc, caption

I have written a custom latex `.cls` file to establish a typesetting workflow for the scientific journals of my research institute. The texts should be written in Markdown and then be processed with `pandoc` to LaTeX.

I already have an elaborated pandoc template to produce the LaTeX preambel etc. So far its working great.

But for the figures I need the caption from the Markdown file to be set with `\sidecaption` instead of `\caption` in LaTeX, as well as with an optional argument (short-caption) for the image attribution in the list of figures.

To get the latter working I use the following template from a GitHub discussion in the [pandoc repo](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7915#issuecomment-1427113349):

```lua
PANDOC_VERSION:must_be_at_least '3.1'

if FORMAT:match 'latex' then
  function Figure(f)
    local short = f.content[1].content[1].attributes['short-caption']
    if short and not f.caption.short then
      f.caption.short = pandoc.Inlines(short)
    end
    return f
  end
end
```

That works without any flaws.

But now I need to figure out how to change the LaTeX macro used for the caption. The older [approach of pre pandoc version 3.0 posted](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7915#issuecomment-1039370851) by @tarleb is really intuitive and I could have easily adapted it to my needs. But since pandoc 3.0 there is the new [*complex figures*](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases?page=2) approach and, so far, I couldn't figure out how to change the LaTeX macro used for the captions with this new behaviour.

I tried something like that (Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71296595/19647155):

```lua
if FORMAT:match 'latex' then
  function RawBlock (raw)
    local caption = raw.text:match('\\caption')
    if caption then
       raw:gsub('\\caption', '\\sidecaption')
    end
    return raw
  end
end
```

But nothing happened.

The main challenge for me are my more-or-less non-existing lua skills. I just never had to use it for my daily tasks. I thought about using `awk` or `sed` to edit the `.tex` file itself using a regex-substitution, but that should remain an absolute stopgap, since it makes the whole workflow less portable.

Thus, I'm hoping for a hint/a solution in form of a pandoc-lua script which 1. helps me to achieve the goal, and 2. improve my understanding of lua and the *complex figures* approach for similar future tasks.

**Edit**

The plain LaTeX solution suggested by Julien is not a real option. The `\caption` macro is very complex in the backend and cannot be copied on the fly via `\let`, `\NewCommandCopy` or something similar. Even after doing so with e.g. `\NewCommandCopy{\oldcaption}{\caption}` and then setting `\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{o m}{\sidecaption[#1]{#2}}` nothing changes and the definition of `\caption`, checked with `\meaning` or something similar, stays the same as before (even `\DeclareDocumentCommand` doesn't work).

In the end, it might be possible to somehow change the `\caption` macro itself. But the effort might not be worth the result (and its more of a question for TeX.SE).

There must be a simpler solution using Lua. Maybe the writer option also suggested by Julien is worth a try. But for that, my missing Lua skills remain as an obstacle. Right now, I'm using a sed script, which works just fine. But it limits the usage to Unix-Systems. Thus, a plain pandoc solution still is the goal to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no easy way to alter or substitute the `\caption` macro with a Lua filter converting from Markdown to Latex using pandoc, because the Latex control sequence used for the caption is kind of hardcoded in the [Haskell Latex writer](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/main/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/LaTeX.hs#L596).

But there is another Lua solution using `Lua(la)tex` which enables the processing of Lua code directly from within the tex document. Therefore, I included the following lines into my custom Latex template called with the `--template` flag in pandoc:

```lua
\ifLuaTeX
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
 local count = 0
 function replace_caption_with_sidecaption(line)
   if string.find(line, "\\begin{figure}.*") then
     in_figure_env = true
   end

   if string.find(line, "\\end{figure}") then
     in_figure_env = false
   end

   if in_figure_env and string.find(line, "^(%s*)\\caption") then
     if count == 0 then
       line = line:gsub("\\caption", "\\sidecaption", 1)
       local count = count + 1
     end
   end
   return line
 end
\end{luacode*}
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", replace_caption_with_sidecaption, "replace_caption_with_sidecaption")}
\fi
```

This code substitutes evert `\caption` string with `\sidecaption` as long as it is located inside a `figure` environment and there the first macro of the line.

It works great, but, of course, makes `Lualatex` the mandatory compilation program.

Answer (score 1):

Lua filters only change Pandoc's AST representation of your document, i.e. before it is then converted to LaTeX. A Raw block filter will not act on Pandoc's LaTeX output, but only on Raw LaTeX blocks that are in the markdown itself.

A Pandoc solution would be to write a [custom Lua *writer*](https://pandoc.org/custom-writers.html). The writer would use pandoc.write to generate Pandoc's own LaTeX output (body only) and modify it with regular expressions or Lua patterns. To replace just a command name this is fairly easy, though longer than the third solution below.

A LaTeX solution is to redefine \caption as \sidecaption:

```
\renewcommand{\caption}{\sidecaption}
```

You can keep this in groups ({...}) to ensure that the redefinition only applies locally.

A hybrid Pandoc/LaTeX solution is a Lua filter that insert LaTeX code to redefine \caption around figures:

```lua
if FORMAT:match 'latex' then
  function Figure (elem)
      return {
         pandoc.RawBlock('latex','{\\renewcommand{\\caption}{\\subcaption}'),
         elem,
         pandoc.RawBlock('latex','}')
      }
  end
end
```

This replaces any 'Figure' block element by a list (succession) of three raw LaTeX blocks. The output should look like:

```
{\renewcommand{\caption}{\subcaption}
... Pandoc's LaTeX for the figure ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatley, your suggestion of a LaTeX solution is impossible due to following reasons: 1. `\sidecaption` itself uses the `\caption` command inside its definition, so you cannot simply replace one with the other, but 2. even if you save the `caption` command (e.g. with `\let` or `\NewCommandCopy`) and use the saved version inside `\sidecaption`, it will not work since `\caption` istn't a simple macro. It relies on many conditions and sub-macros in the backend. See my edit.

Comment: But the creation of a writer seems to be a real possibility. I'll check this out ASAP. If you could provide such a solution, I would appreciate it very much!